# How to find special characters in a particular attribute of json data stored in mongodb using mongo query

Tags: mongodb

how to search any special characters in a particular nested json object field. Am having a field which stores nested json data.

I need to write a MongoDB query to fetch all the names which is having special characters

Student collection:

Example:

```
{
_id:123
student: {
      "personalinfo":{
             "infoid": "YYY21"
             "name": "test@#!*"
                     }
         } 
}
```

I have tried few regular expressions but I am not sure how to loop in array elements

I expect it to print the infoid & name, which has special characters in the name field.

Comment: Could you please update the question with the actual document as there is no array in the current example

Comment: I have updated it.. its not an array.. kind of nested json..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query can do the trick:

```
db.collection.distinct("student.personalinfo.name",{"student.personalinfo.name": { $not: /^[\w]+[\w ]*$/ } })
```

**Data set:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d77a5babd4e75c58d59821d"),
    "student" : {
        "personalinfo" : {
            "infoid" : "YYY21",
            "name" : "test@#!*"
        }
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d77a5babd4e75c58d59821e"),
    "student" : {
        "personalinfo" : {
            "infoid" : "YYY21",
            "name" : "Bruce##"
        }
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d77a5babd4e75c58d59821f"),
    "student" : {
        "personalinfo" : {
            "infoid" : "YYY21",
            "name" : "Tony"
        }
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d77a5babd4e75c58d598220"),
    "student" : {
        "personalinfo" : {
            "infoid" : "YYY21",
            "name" : "Natasha"
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[ "test@#!*", "Bruce##" ]
```

Comment: Thanks Mr.S.Sharma! But somehow its not working for my data.. {
    "StudentData" : "{\n  \"studentid\" : \"123224343\",\n  \"year\" : \"2019\",\n 
 "personalinfo\" : 
                   [ {\n    \"infoid\" : \"YYY21\",\n    \"name\" : \"test@#!*\",\n } ]\n}"
}

Comment: @SooryaT This document structure is different than you posted in the question. Can you please tell me what did you try?

Comment: I just noticed that they had changed the structure.. With above same case, i want to find the names & count of names which are having special characters

Answer (score 0):

Try using below regex, it matches all unicode punctuation and symbols.

```
dbname.find({'student.name':{$regex:"[\p{P}\p{S}]"}})
```

Comment: but name comes under the personalinfo parent.. so should it be student.personalinfo.name?